# Override Bootstrap 5 Colors

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I wan't to override the `$blue` variable in Bootstrap SASS. `$primary` and `$secondary` are working, but not the `$blue, $teal, $orange` and the rest of the other colors that aren't theme colors. This is my SASS file:

```
// COLORS
$primary: #D91473;
$secondary: #2E3092;
$blue: #349DD6;
$teal: #309C9E;


@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables';

// Bootstrap Main
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

My markup is just a simple:

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-blue">
     <p>test</p>
</div>
```

As you can see in the class, it's `bg-blue`, which does not work but `bg-primary` works.

Comment: It doesn't look that `bg-blue` class exists anywhere in bootstrap. Your override might actually be working, you can test if it does by using `$blue` variable directly somewhere in your own class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.bg-blue` is not a utility class that is generated by Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/background/).  So while you may be overriding the `$blue` color successfully, you are changing nothing about whether it is included in the collection that is used to generate the `.bg-` classes.

At a glance, it appears that all the `.bg-` prefixed classes are generated from the [theme colors map](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/color/#theme-colors).  Following the [section of the docs that describes how to add to this map](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/sass/#add-to-map), you probably want to do something like:

```
// Create your own map
$custom-colors: (
  "blue": $blue
);

// Merge the maps
$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-colors);
```

Note that this means that the blue color is now part of the theme colors collection and will be run through *all* processing that that collection is run through, so you may find it adds additional utility classes you weren't expecting or has other side effects.  You might instead be able to to instead find a way to plug into the process for generating the background colors, which would be more of a precision operation, but probably more complex to implement.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification. Because of this, to be safe, I made my own utility class for ```bg-blue``` by declaring ```.bg-blue { background-color: $blue }``` in a separate sass file.